# How to use double click on desktop to act as a shortcut for a few commands

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder

Until I shifted to Mac I used to use an app called Fences in Windows to hide desktop by double clicking the desktop. I wanted a similar app to do this on the Mac OS X Mavericks but I have no clue how to do it. The closest app I made is using a global shortcut key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (using the idea I found on GitHub at [MASShortcutDemo](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcutDemo) to toggle between hide and show of desktop.

Basically it ran the following commands and set a flag as desktop is hidden

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool false; killall Finder
```

Pressing shortcut again ran these commands to revert it

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool true; killall Finder
```

I want to know if this is possible to just double click on the desktop and make this happen pretty much like Fences on Windows. I have already tried an app called HideDesktop which works fairly simple but would love to know how to get this done.

Comment: Command + Shift + H is already built in; why would you need to build an application for it?

Comment: The application changes the functionality of the shortcut. I could use any keyboard combo. I just need to know how to use a mouse shortcut (double click in this case) rather than a keyboard combo such as Command + Shift + H or any other combo that I assign. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

To hide other all other open applications windows while in another:

<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + (mouse click)

by clicking on it's dock icon

Comment: That doesn't help. Please do read my post again, I need a mouse shortcut (double click on desktop) to hide / show the icons. And not a existing shortcut to hide windows. I need to hide desktop icons not application windows!

I need a macintosh version of what is considered a Shell hook on Windows to hook into the desktop so that I could manipulate it